# Retrieve Records faster from whole dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, dask

I have csv file with 109 Million records. So, I'm using dask to load the dataset in python. And I want to get record with one condition.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv(file)
df[df[column] ==  'ABC'].head()
```

Now even though the value is present in the file it's not returning anything and I figured out it's because it has loaded in 400 partitions and it's just finding in the last partion, so I mentioned `blocksize=None` while reading the file so I'll get just one block as whole.

```
df = dd.read_csv(file, blocksize=None)
```

And now when I'm trying to look for the record it's running out of memory, any way where I can look for record in whole dataframe? or how can I look for record in whole df after partioning.

Answer (score 1):

There is a keyword option in `.head()` which specifies how many partitions to search:

```py
# search just the first two partitions
df[df[column] == 'ABC'].head(npartitions=2) 

# search all the partitions
df[df[column] == 'ABC'].head(npartitions=-1)
```

Searching across all partitions somewhat defeats the purpose of a quick lookup using `.head()`, so if your intention is to locate a specific set of records that fit into client memory, then it might be better to use `.compute`:

```py
# find records (on all partitions) and store them as pandas df
specific_record = df[df[column] == 'ABC'].compute()
```